# Using different cluster distance modes across iterations during agglomerative clustering?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

Agglomerative clustering can be done by using `single-linkage`, `complete-linkage`, `average`, `weighted`, `centroid`, `median` and `ward` distances. The slink algorithm and nearest-neighbour clustering techniques allow use to do hierarchical clustering with the above distance modes in `O(n^2)` time complexity given `n` samples.

Generally, we choose and stick to a single distance mode for all iterations during the clustering process. Is it possible to choose a different distance mode after each iteration instead and still have a `O(n^2)` complexity for the algorithm?

i.e. 
Iteration 1 - Single Linkage 
Iteration 2 - Ward 
Iteration 3 - Average 
. 
. 
. 
Iteration n (Last) - Ward